# vimeo player events not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, vimeo

> I want to hide iframe and show image thumbnail when iframe video
>   playback reaches the end. But none of the Vimeo player api event 
>   working. Can anybody help me? Here is my code:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UTt2K/973/)

```
$("#video .playBtnOrangeMid").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $("#video1").attr("src","http://player.vimeo.com/video/69185765?color=de641b&autoplay=1&api=1&amp;player_id=video1");
        $("#video").css("background","none");
            var iframe = $('#video1')[0],
            player = $f(iframe);
            player.addEvent('ready', function() {
                player.addEvent('finish', function(){
                    $("#video .playBtnOrangeMid").show();
                    $("#video1").attr("src","");
                    $("#video").css("background","url(../images/thumb1.png)");
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Post your HTML also, even a fiddle will help us understand your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UTt2K/973/

Comment: Hey , i dont understand ,you know, on fiddle it is working great, but in my web page it is troubling

Comment: Have you checked by putting alert box inside `player.addEvent('finish', function(){` to confirm that the finish event is triggered. Also check is any of the three lines inside this function works or where it stops. Also the image URL.